# Spring select desired bean implementation

Tags: java, spring

I have a prototype-scoped bean in Spring web application (I am using Spring annotations), lets call it MainBean, that uses one of the implementations of IOtherBean via dependency injection.

The problem I have is that we dont know until the run-time which implementation we need to use. When we call one method of MainBean (lets say doStuff(String param)), it should determine based on the param value which implementation to choose.

Currently I just do it by autowiring ApplicationContext into MainBean and calling appContext.getBean() based on the param value and that works fine.

I was wondering is there a cleaner way of doing it? If those were not Spring managed beans I would have used Factory pattern to instantiate correct one. Is there something similar in Spring? From what I read I cant see how I can use Spring factory-bean to do what I want at run-time.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code example? What you say is not making much sense. If you have multiple beans from one interface (IOtherBean) all the beans will have the same method with same param value.

When you inject using the interface type, I really do not see a choice until you employ some factory pattern and static factory method there.

Did you try using @Qualifier annotation and using the qualifier name while injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually by using `ApplicationContext.getBean()` **you already use** factory pattern, just Spring's one. The `getBean()` method is declared in `BeanFactory` interface which `ApplicationContext` extends. So what you are currently doing is OK for me.